# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): register is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, typeerror, onsubmit

Getting this error for register when onSubmit is initiated. I've been trying to debug it for the last couple days, and even had a second set of eyes try as well with no luck.

The solutions that i've tried so far include checking to see if register was exported correctly, reviewing if the destructuring was handled correctly, and if I was calling the function with proper syntax. Each of these seem to check out, which leads me to being stumped and not sure how to resolve the issue.

**Console error:**

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: register is not a function
    onSubmit Register.js:30
    onSubmit Register.js:39
```

**Setting up register:**

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { setAlert } from './alert'
import {
  REGISTER_SUCCESS,
  REGISTER_FAIL,
} from './types'


// Register user
export const register = ({ name, email, password }) => async dispatch => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }

  const body = JSON.stringify({ name, email, password })

  try {
    const res = await axios.post('/u', body, config)

    dispatch({
      type: REGISTER_SUCCESS,
      payload: res.data
    })

    // dispatch(loadUser())
  } catch (err) {
    const errors = err.response.data.errors

    if (errors) {
      errors.forEach(error => dispatch(setAlert(error.msg, 'danger')))
    }

    dispatch({
      type: REGISTER_FAIL
    })
  }
}
```

**Register form:**

````
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import axios from 'axios'
import { Container, Form, Col, Row, Button } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { setAlert } from '../actions/alert'
import { register } from '../actions/auth'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

export const Register = ({ setAlert, register }) => {

  const [ formData, setFormData ] = useState({
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    username: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',
    password2: ''
  })

  const { firstName, lastName, email, username, password, password2 } = formData

  const onChange = e => setFormData({ ...formData, [ e.target.name ]: e.target.value })

  const onSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (password !== password2) {
      setAlert('Passwords do not match', 'danger')
    } else {
      register({ firstName, lastName, username, email, password })
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h4 className="text-center my-3">Create account</h4>
      <Container className="d-flex mx-auto justify-content-center bottomPaddingGap">
        <Row className="d-flex flex-column">
          <Form onSubmit={e => onSubmit(e)}>
            <Row>
              <Col md="auto">
                <Form.Group className="mt-3">
                  <Form.Label>First name</Form.Label>
                  <Form.Control
                    required
                    type="text"
                    name="firstName"
                    placeholder="John"
                    value={firstName}
                    onChange={e => onChange(e)}
                  />
                </Form.Group>
              </Col>
              <Col md="auto">
                <Form.Group className="mt-3">
                  <Form.Label>Last name</Form.Label>
                  <Form.Control
                    required
                    type="text"
                    name="lastName"
                    placeholder="Doe"
                    value={lastName}
                    onChange={e => onChange(e)}
                  />
                </Form.Group>
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row>
              <Col md="auto">
                <Form.Group className="mt-3">
                  <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
                  <Form.Control
                    required
                    type="email"
                    name="email"
                    value={email}
                    onChange={e => onChange(e)}
                  />
                </Form.Group>
              </Col>
              <Col md="auto">
                <Form.Group className="mt-3">
                  <Form.Label>Username</Form.Label>
                  <Form.Control
                    required
                    type="text"
                    name="username"
                    placeholder="@"
                    value={username}
                    onChange={e => onChange(e)}
                  />
                </Form.Group>
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row>
              <Col md="auto">
                <Form.Group className="mt-3">
                  <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                  <Form.Control
                    required
                    type="password"
                    name="password"
                    minLength="6"
                    value={password}
                    onChange={e => onChange(e)}
                  />
                </Form.Group>
              </Col>
              <Col md="auto">
                <Form.Group className="mt-3">
                  <Form.Label>Confirm password</Form.Label>
                  <Form.Control
                    required
                    type="password"
                    name="password2"
                    minLength="6"
                    value={password2}
                    onChange={e => onChange(e)}
                  />
                </Form.Group>
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <Form.Group className="mt-3">
              <Form.Control
                type="submit"
                value="Create your account"
                className="btn btn-primary"
              />
            </Form.Group>
          </Form>
          <div className="text-center mt-3 border-top">
            <p className="text-muted pt-3 mb-1">Already have an account?</p>
            <Link to="/login" className="noDecor">
              <div className="d-grid gap-2">
                <Button variant="secondary">Log In</Button>
              </div>
            </Link>
          </div>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </>
  )
}

Register.propTypes = {
  setAlert: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  register: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default connect(null, { setAlert, register })(Register)```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bGce.png
````

Comment: Are you passing the register function as a prop while rendering the Register component ? (something like - <Register register={register}></Register>)

Comment: How you import `Register` component?

Comment: be aware of name conflicts - I see multiple `register` in your code. It could be that Typescript used the wrong `register`